# How to use sudo for gem command in chef

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am triying to provision with chef. I need ruby and rubygems for root user and another user 'deploy'

ruby and rubygems are installed and work for root user (in test case "vagrant").

I create one user for use after with capistrano in order to deploy my app

```ruby
user 'deploy' do
  password '$1$zOC.txvE$ex544C.YpxV.HqNh/2AKQ0'
  home "/home/deploy"
  supports :manage_home => true
  shell "/bin/bash"
end
```

Then I try to change gem sources for this 'deploy' user

```ruby
execute 'change sources to our gem server' do
  command "gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/ && gem sources -a http://my.gem.server/"
  creates "~/.gemrc"
  user 'deploy'
  cwd "/home/deploy"
end
```

but get this error

```
[2014-02-14T14:38:27+00:00] ERROR: execute[change sources to our gem server] (beesor-cookbook::user line 13) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'       
---- Begin output of gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/ && gem sources -a http://my.gem.server/ ----       
STDOUT: source http://rubygems.org/ not present in cache       
STDERR: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)       
    Permission denied - /home/vagrant/.gemrc       
---- End output of gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/ && gem sources -a http://my.gem.server/ ----       
Ran gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/ && gem sources -a http://my.gem.server/ returned 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem with using an `execute` resource. You are running the execute resource as a non-privileged user. However, you want the associated file to still be owned by the non-privledged user, right? The code that Stephen suggested will work, but the `.gemrc` will be owned by the root user. Depending on how Rubygems reads it's gemrcs, it may not like that the file is owned by a different user. So you'll either need to manually `chown` and `chmod` the file inside the `execute` command, or just use a template.

If you run the command locally on your machine, you'll see the generated gemrc looks like:

```
---
:sources:
- http://my.gem.server
```

I would recommend using a pure `template` resource instead:

```rb
template '/home/deploy/.gemrc' do
  source 'gemrc.erb'
  user 'deploy'
  group 'deploy'
  mode '0644'
  variables(source: 'http://my.gem.server')
end
```

And then the associated erb:

```
---
:sources:
- <%= @source %>
```

This could also be expanded to support multiple source endpoints. Additionally, because you're using an idempotent resource:

- You get a nice diff output in the Chef Client run

  You'll see a git-style diff in the output, which is very useful for debugging
- You can notify other resources of a change

  If you need to install a gem after the template sources have change (for example), you can safely use notifications for this. Those notifications will only trigger when the template has changed:

```rb
template '/home/deploy/.gemrc' do
  # ...
  notifies :install, 'gem_package[foo]', :immediately
end

gem_package 'foo' do
  action :nothing
end
```

Comment: the EACCES is on /home/vagrant/.gemrc not /home/deploy/.gemrc so I think the user is actually running into CHEF-2288 (i.e. ENV['HOME'] is wrong), but your solution to replace the execute resource with the template resource mitigates it all correctly anyway...